# How to reset form functionality if previously e.preventDefault() was on it's button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have a form which naturally does its thing and above form there are 3 Bootstrap tabs with some text. If a specific tab for Camp is open then instead of form passing data to its page it should redirect user to a contact page. This works, but if user clicked a tab for Camp and then change tab to something else, form doesn't reset it's functionality.

How can I remove `e.preventDefault()` inside `reset_form()` and let the form does it's thing?

```
    var $reservationBtn= $("#js-reservation-btn");

    // Don't send form to it's page, but redirect user to Contact page
    function redirect_form_to_contact_page() {
        $reservationBtn.on('click', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/contact';
        });
    }

    // Reset form so it works normally
    function reset_form() {
        $reservationBtn.on('click', function(e) {
            return true;
        });
    }

    // Depending on a tab clicked redirect to Contact or reset form
    $("#reservation__list a").click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('js-reservation-tab-btn-camp')) {
            redirect_form_to_contact_page();
        }
        else {
            reset_form();
        }

    });
```

Comment: I don't understand why people keep using preventDefault() on what is probably a submit button. If you use a normal button instead of a submit button, the form will never submit automatically, so you don't have to preventDefault() the event. Then you can just write the logic as: "if someLogic then redirect else submit" with one click event instead of having to juggle 2-3 different click events and timing when to unbind which one.

Comment: Fair insight, I didn't think about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click event

```
$reservationBtn.unbind('click');
```